# gunicorn on heroku: binding to localhost

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn, procfile

I've been following the tutorial on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#declare-process-types-with-procfile.
It went smoothly except for one thing that bothers me.

After starting foreman I should see the following:

```
$ foreman start
2013-04-03 16:11:22 [8469] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.2
2013-04-03 16:11:22 [8469] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (8469)
```

However, I get:

```
Starting gunicorn 17.5
Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

How can I change it so that it listens only to my local machine (ie. 127.0.0.1)?

My Procfile contains only

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi
```

thanks!

Comment: are you sure you're using foreman locally? `http://0.0.0.0:5000` is the standard public URL that heroku provides when you push your project to them.

Comment: At that stage in the tutorial there was no pushing to heroku (there wasn't even a git repo).  Is gunicorn's default binding 127.0.0.1:8000 or 0.0.0.0:5000?

Comment: I believe  local it's 127 and on heroku 0.0.0.

Comment: so then in my case it is not configured properly because it doesn't seem be doing that (see my follow up question).

Comment: follow up question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433550/gunicorn-on-heruko-binding-to-localhost-without-messing-up-deployment-to-heruko

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks to be the default IP address used when you run use gunicorn to serve a WSGI app with foreman.

Running your django app without foreman like this:

```
gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi:application
```

Will bind it to gunicorn's default, `127.0.0.1:8000`

```
2013-08-23 00:02:54 [45352] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 17.5
2013-08-23 00:02:54 [45352] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (45352)
2013-08-23 00:02:54 [45352] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-08-23 00:02:54 [45355] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 45355
```

And specifying in your `Procfile` which binding to use:

```
web: gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 hellodjango.wsgi
```

Will bind it to `127.0.0.1:8000`, or whatever you specify.

```
00:06:26 web.1  | started with pid 45384
00:06:26 web.1  | 2013-08-23 00:06:26 [45384] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 17.5
00:06:26 web.1  | 2013-08-23 00:06:26 [45384] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (45384)
00:06:26 web.1  | 2013-08-23 00:06:26 [45384] [INFO] Using worker: sync
00:06:26 web.1  | 2013-08-23 00:06:26 [45387] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 45387
```

I'd be interested to find exactly where foreman tells gunicorn to use `0.0.0.0` as a default.

Comment: You've answered my question, thanks for that!  And I too would like to know where the default is set.  The tutorial skipped this part, since they got the 127.0.0.1 binding but didn't use the -b option in the gunicorn command.

Comment: @Hamlet I'm actually encountering this exact same problem today, with gunicorn laughing at `0.0.0.0`. This might be a good bug to report. Are you on Linux 13.04 too?

Comment: @agconti No, Mac OSX Lion.  What were you using before, when you had it working correctly?

Comment: @Hamlet windows 8 surprisingly.

Comment: Interesting, I'm on OSX too - perhaps relevant?

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel Did you also encounter this problem?  Btw, did you get a chance to take a look at the follow up question?